# Can Unicode canonical caseless matching be implemented in XSD?

Tags: xml, unicode, xsd

I am working on an XML schema for a data model that involves case-insensitive keys, drawn from substantially all Unicode characters.  In this context, "case-insensitive" is defined in terms of the Unicode canonical caseless matching algorithm (definition D145 in [Chapter 3 of version 10.0 of the Unicode specification](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G33992)).  Caseless matching doesn't mesh well with XSD 1.1 identity constraints, so I am considering various alternatives for defining the necessary key-uniqueness constraints, ideally without losing the original, un-normalized form of the keys.

At the moment I am looking simply to constrain the keys to be presented in case-folded normalized form consistent with canonical caseless matching, so that they are directly comparable with each other.  For this to be useful, it must not depend on extensions or implementation-specific behaviors, though I'm willing to rely on well-defined optional behaviors, such as using the `unicode-normalize()` XPath function to normalize to form NFD.

In the future, I may also want to validate that two strings are canonical caseless matches of each other (i.e constraining two attribute values or an element's text content and one of its attribute values to be canonical caseless matches of each other), but that's a separate question.

Here's a simplified example schema that I think comes pretty close to doing what I want:

```
<xsd:schema
    version="1.1"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:my="urn:x-myns"
    targetNamespace="urn:x-myns"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xsd:element name="table" type="my:tableType">
    <xsd:key name="keyKey">
      <xsd:selector xpath="my:entry"/>
      <xsd:field xpath="@key"/>
    </xsd:key>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:complexType name="tableType">
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="entry" type="my:entryType"
                   minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="entryType">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
      <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:attribute name="key" type="xsd:string"/>

        <!-- MY BEST ATTEMPT SO FAR: -->
        <xsd:assert test="@key=fn:unicode-normalize(fn:lower-case(
            fn:unicode-normalize(@key, 'NFD')), 'NFD')" />

      </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

</xsd:schema>
```

That's sufficient for rejecting

```
<table xmlns="urn:x-myns">
  <entry key="Clé">Value1</entry>
</table>
```

("Clé" should be presented as "cle&#x0301;" or an equivalent representation of the same character sequence), but it doesn't exactly match the data's native canonicalization, because Unicode case folding is not equivalent to lower-casing in some instances. So,

- is there a way to produce a true Unicode case-folded normalized form in this context, subject to the limitations I presented?
- do I actually need that?  If the form tested by the assertion in my schema serves as a basis for caseless matching behavior that always produces the same results as Unicode's standard canonical caseless matching algorithm, then I can live with what I've got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ask:

> is there a way to produce a true Unicode case-folded normalized form in this context, subject to the limitations I presented?

If by "true Unicode case-folded normalized form" you mean the result of applying the Unicode Case_Folding() mapping to the string, I think the answer is (probably) "no", and this is why.

For the approach you are using, you need a function (or as in your example a composition of functions) you can call in the assertion.  So it should be possible to get a true case-folded form if and only if there is a simple composition of built-in functions you can call to produce it.

If Case_Folding were just a matter of substituting new characters for old, one could in theory handle it with a call to `translate()`, but the argument strings would be unmanageable.  But Case_Folding maps (if I have understood the document you point to correctly) some characters to strings (and/or some strings to strings), which puts it out of reach for `translate()`.

Without going entry by entry through the case-folding and lower-casing entries in the Unicode character database, I don't know that it's possible to prove for certain that it cannot be done.  (Perhaps a call to lower-case() followed by judicious use of replace() would do the trick -- but I would expect it to be too unwieldy.

One could of course write an XQuery or XSLT function to do the case-folding operation (as opposed to lower-casing and upper-casing).  But there is no way to declare a function within an XSD assertion.

If you can find an XSD schema validator willing to accept XPath 3.0 instead of 2.0, then writing your own function would be theoretically possible.  But again it would be cumbersome unless you could offload as many of the details as possible to an XML representation of the Unicode database, which means it will work only if the XSD processor is willing to evaluate calls to doc().

So in practice I think the answer is no, unless you are willing to go to unusual lengths to make it happen *and* also have some luck.

> do I actually need that? If the form tested by the assertion in my schema serves as a basis for caseless matching behavior that always produces the same results as Unicode's standard canonical caseless matching algorithm, then I can live with what I've got.

I think here, too, the answer is "no".  The fourth paragraph of the section "Default Case Folding" at the URI you point to reads:

> Any two strings which are considered to be case variants of each other under any of the full
>   case conversions, toUppercase(X), toLowercase(X), or toTitlecase(X) will fold to the same
>   string by the toCasefold(X) operation

Since the XPath lower-case() function is specified as implementing the Unicode lower-case mapping, I think that gives you the result that any strings S1 and S2 for which lower-case($S1) eq lower-case($S2) will be equal under the Unicode toCasefold() operation.  The wording of the paragraph in Unicode leaves open the possibility that some strings which are not case variants of each other will *also* fold to the same string under toCasefold(), but I hope all they mean is that case folding affects normalization as well as casing. If so, then I think your call to unicode-normalize() will handle those cases.  (If there are other pairs of strings for which toCasefold() returns equal values, but unicode-normalize(lower-case()) does not, then your assertion will fail to accept some pairs you would prefer to accept.  But what would those pairs of strings be?)

This answer is less crisp than I wish I could make it, and I doubt I've told you anything you don't already know.  Without more time for research in the Unicode database than I have time for, I don't think a more definitive answer is likely to be possible.  But if you were mostly hoping for an independent observer to confirm that you seem to be on the right track, I can certainly do that.  Good work!  And good luck!

Comment: I don't buy your argument that the difference between `fn:lower-case()` and Unicode `toCaseFold()` doesn't make a difference.  Unicode seems to be saying that `toCaseFold(s) == toCaseFold(lower-case(s))` for all Unicode strings `s`, but it does not follow from there that `toCaseFold(s) == lower-case(s)`, or that `unicode-normalize(toCaseFold(s), 'NFD') == unicode-normalize(lower-case(s), 'NFD')`.  (My apologies for the pseudo-expressions mixing XPath and Unicode-specification functions.)

Comment: Nevertheless, I appreciate the confirmation that I can't have what I want (ob-Jagger here).  I think what I have is a reasonable approximation, and from a documentary perspective I think it is satisfactory.  I hope so, anyway, because I don't see a way to do better.

Comment: On the relation of toCaseFold() and lower-case(), you've persuaded me that the Unicode spec means what you say.  Fwiw, though, I think the key condition for your question, however, is not the one you cite but whether for all s and t `unicode-normalize(lower-case(s), 'NFD') == unicode-normalize(lower-case(t),'NFD') iff toCaseFold(s) == toCaseFold(t)`.

Comment: You've made a good observation, @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen, that I don't necessarily need the condition I cited in my earlier comment, but I don't think you've captured it, either.  For the key computation using `lower-case()` to serve my purpose equivalently to a hypothetical key computation using `toCaseFold()`, what I need is `unicode-normalize(lower-case(s), 'NFD') == unicode-normalize(lower-case(t),'NFD') iff unicode-normalize(toCaseFold(s), 'NFD') == unicode-normalize(toCaseFold(t),'NFD')`.  The latter equality is not equivalent to `toCaseFold(s) == toCaseFold(t)`.